# Creating Integer Primary key value using the following query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Discuss the following SQL query with respect to performance in an application involving more number of concurrent users creating and deleting records. The objective is to create continuous primary key integer values.

```
Table name: SitePage

Column DataType
--------- -----------

PageID BigINT

PageName nchar(10)
```

Query to insert new record

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 0
WHILE (@intFlag =0)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
Insert into SitePage (PageID, PageName) values ((Select max(PageID)+1  from SitePage), CONCAT('Page ID : ', (Select max(PageID)+1  from SitePage)));
set @intFlag = @@rowcount
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SET @intFlag=0
END CATCH

END
GO
```

1. We don't want to use auto increment integer value for primary key
   because of the following
   [reason](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity)
2. We also don't want to use SEQUENCE
3. We can't do trace flag 272

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen that Connect item before.  Did you look at the workarounds there?  What about putting 1001 dummy records into the table?

Comment: The connect item says "If the identity value is already over 1000, no reseed occurs."  That makes me think you can just create the table with identity seed = 1001.

Comment: When you test in your local db, it increases sequentially like 1001,1002,1003 but when you restart your sql server it reseeds from 10000, look at the following interesting article showing demo http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is

Comment: I don't see it jump 10000 in that demo, it only jumped up to 1000, and that was when the seed was at 3.

Comment: just tested in my local db, after every restart it jumps 10000 for bigint datatype

Comment: what if you set the identity seed to 10001?

Comment: Din't work. started with 10001 inserted 100 records, restarted, inserted 100 records now started from 20002 again jumping of 10000 values

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** use "select max()+1" to get a unique id. The number one reason is that with concurrent users, that value has absolutely **no** guarantee of being unique - two users running anywhere close to simultaneously can end up with the same value. Don't do it. Ever. That's why things like auto-number and sequences exist.

Comment: That is reason using While if there is conflict it would iterate for the next possible value and successfull insertion. Don't want to use auto increment because of the following reason http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity and don't want to use SEQUENCE because for 50 tables i have to create 50 sequences

Comment: Fair enough, you WILL get unique values. However, other reasons not to do this are: every insert will require a full table scan or at least an index scan, which is a SIGNIFICANT amount of extra work to thrust upon your db. And each failed insert involves a constraint popping an exception, followed by ANOTHER table or index scan. Too much work for an id!

Comment: You have to create 50 _tables_ for 50 tables, so what's the big deal with creating 50 companion sequences? You're also creating 50 Primary Key constraints, 50 indexing schemes, etc. Sequences can be looked at as just "one of those things" you have to do per table.